# Why am I getting "Unexpected property rootFolderOrFile" when trying to run JMeter?

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to test an app service using JMeter in Azure Pipelines. I run this code from my YAML-file:

```
- job: JMeter
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    steps:
     - task: JMeterInstaller@0
       displayName: 'Install JMeter 5.3'
       inputs:
         jmeterVersion: '5.3'
     - task: Bash@3
       displayName: 'Run JMeter test'
       inputs:
         rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/JMeter'
         script:  
          jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l myTtest.csv -e -o Result
```

But I am getting an error message: **Unexpected property rootFolderOrFile**. I put this property to indicate the file which contains the test plan (**test.jmx**). I tried with `targetType: inline` and the pipeline shows stage succeeded, but I can not find the **myTest.csv** and the resuts folder **Result** therefore I thought to change the `targetType` to `filePath` can fix my code.
Apparently No!
Can anyone help me or guide me to find why I am getting the error?
Or Is this the wrong way?

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The task version you used it version 3, it does not have the field `rootFolderOrFile`, you could try below script.

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/JMeter'
    arguments: 'jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l myTtest.csv -e -o Result'
```

In addition, I found a [blog](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9), you could also check it.

**Update1**

If the file JMeter is in the root, the field `filePath` should be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/JMeter`

Yaml definition

```
- task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Bash Script'
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/JMeter'
        arguments: 'jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l myTtest.csv -e -o Result'
```

By the way, we could add the task bash and enter the script `ls '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'` to check the working directory files.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I am getting: [error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/home/vsts/work/1/s/JMeter'

Comment: Hi @carl, Sorry for my mistake, I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: Same error: [error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/JMeter'

Comment: I tried: inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: | 
          jmeter -n -t JMeter/test.jmx -l JMeter/myTest.csv -e -o Result ----the pipeline was succeed, but I cannot find myTest.csv or the folder Result !!!

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find myTest.csv or the folder Result

To solve this issue, you need to specify the output path for the `myTest.csv` file.

If you run the command: `jmeter -n -t JMeter/test.jmx -l JMeter/myTest.csv -e -o Result`

The `myTest.csv` file will be created in the **JMeter folder** instead of **Result Folder.**

So the correct command is that:

```
jmeter -n -t JMeter/test.jmx -l JMeter/Result/myTest.csv -e -o Result
```

[image]